# regex - Match pattern without prefix before pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match amounts without `$`. I've tried `(?<!\$)\d+\.\d{2}` so far. It's probably something simple but I'm missing it :(

strings

```
$100.00 50.00
1.99 $150.50 200.00
```

How would get the match to be below?

```
50.00
1.99 200.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI: you should provide more realistic examples because right now, you may just solve the issue by splitting with whitespace and returning all items that do not start with `$`:

```
[x for x in text.split() if not x.startswith('$')]
```

I would include a digit check into the negative lookahead and also add a digit check on the right (since the `\d{2}` only matches two digits, but does not prevent from matching when there are 3 or more).

```
r'(?<![$\d])\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hTcMaK/1).

**Details**

- `(?<![$\d])` - no `$` or digit allowed immediately on the left
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed on the right.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/a3Xd9i):

```
import re
text = "$100.00 50.00\n1.99 $150.50 200.00"
print( [x for x in text.split() if not x.startswith('$')] )
# => ['50.00', '1.99', '200.00']
print( re.findall(r'(?<![$\d])\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d)', text) )
# => ['50.00', '1.99', '200.00']
```